# Node.js canvas module on windows 7(32 bits)

Tags: node.js, node-canvas

I am unable to install the canvas module on nodejs.I found the errors shown in the attached image.[enter link description here http://inkfi.com/error-images/error.png](http://inkfi.com/error-images/error.png)[Click to see full image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CThVA.png)

Answer (score 0):

Do any other npm modules with native bindings work for you? I *think* your issue is node-gyp on windows. See [the node-gyp docs/rep](https://github.com/TooTallNate/node-gyp) for more info. (You need python and some other goodies.)